# R - problem with fitting to a custom non-linear equation

Tags: r, fitting, nls

I have a problem. In GraphPad Prism, fitting to the following equation
[image]

my data produce pretty nice results. However, when I try to repeat in R, it generates terrible output. Here is the code:

```
require(data.table)
require(tidyverse)
require(minpack.lm)

s <- rev(accumulate(rep(max_conc, n), ~.x/2))
y <- c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.13, 0.41, 0.67, 0.81, 0.86, 0.87, 0.89, 0.91)

nlsLM(y ~ Bottom + (Top - Bottom) * (E + s + Kd - sqrt((E + s + Kd) ^ 2 - 4 * E * s) / 2), start = list(Bottom = 0, Top = 1, E = 1, Kd = 1))

Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

Do you have any suggestions about what I am missing or doing wrong? When the data is plotted in a way that x = log10(s) and y = y it produces a perfect curve. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. using the same starting values as in GraphPad does not help

Comment: I see [S]_0 three times in your formula. Why do you replace only one occurence with `x` in your R code?

Comment: @Roland you are right, my mistake, thank you for pointing this out. Anyway, the problem persists

Comment: The formula is still not the same. You are not dividing by E0. Also, I would replace E with `exp(e)` to avoid division by zero. You might want to also enforce bondaries on `Top` and `Bottom`.

Comment: Thanks, now everything works :)